# How to re-activate WebStorm IDE unit tests left toolbar with Jest?

Tags: jestjs, webstorm

Since last week unit test buttons (left bar) disappeared. How can I re-activate them in WebStorm, currently running in Jest/Angular?
Even after reinstall all (`npm cache verify` / `npm install`) and restarting  WebStorm the unit test controls are gone. I don't want to reset the IDE.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it by running `rm -rf .idea` in the root project folder, and restart the IDE